# Unable to change state

Tags: reactjs

Expected behaviour: The app should display John at first and then I change the state (name) to George (setTimeout) so that should be displayed.The state doesn't seem to change though.Any ideas?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state={name:"John"};
  }

  render() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState=({name:"George"})
    }, 2000)

    return (
        <div>
        {this.state.name}

        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `this.setState=({name:"George"})` should be `this.setState({name:"George"})`

Comment: Oh,this is embarrassing.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comments you got the way to make your code working. But I would like to add an answer here with the message that it is not good idea to change the state of your component in the render() function.

As when your state changes render() function will be called, which will call setTimeout, it will again change the state ... so you will go into infinite loop of rendering your component.

The right way of during this is to have you setTimeout in the `componentDidMount()` function of your component.